# Scan a string in TCL

Tags: regex, tcl

I'm trying to manipulate a string in TCL and would like to separate out the individual words in a string:

```
word1+word2+word3+word4;;;;blah;blah
```

I've been trying to use scan to pull at least word3 out, and wouldn't mind being able to pull words1,2 and 4 as well. Best that I've been able to do is pull everything up to word4 into a variable and then rescan again, which I figure is pretty inefficient.

Comment: You've been given three useful answers. How about accepting one of them?

Answer (score 0):

You could split on `;` then on `+`:

```
set words [split [split $input ";"] "+"]
```

That gives you a list with the four words at the start. You could then use `lassign` if you're using Tcl 8.5:

```
lassign $words word1 word2 word3 word4
```

If the structure is always the same, regexp could be used as well:

```
regexp -all -- {([^+]*)\+([^+]*)\+([^+]*)\+ ([^;]*)} $words -> word1 word2 word3 word4
```

If you want to use `scan`, it's a bit similar:

```
scan $words {%[^+]+%[^+]+%[^+]+%[^;]} word1 word2 word3 word4
```

---

In all the above, you will get the values of word1, word2, word3 and word4 in the variables `$word1`, `$word2`, `$word3` and `$word4`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what the real data looks like, pulling out all the words comprised of word characters may suffice:

```
set words [regexp -all -inline {\w+} $str]
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`scan` command](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/scan.htm) is quite capable:

```
set data "word1+word2+word3+word4;;;;blah;blah"
scan $data {%[^+]+%[^+]+%[^+]+%[^;];;;;%[^;];%[^;]} w1 w2 w3 w4 b1 b2
puts "w1=$w1, w2=$w2, w3=$w3, w4=$w4, b1=$b1, b2=$b2"
```

The trick is to use `%[^…]` to match the sequences you want to extract, putting the character that marks the end of what you want inside the negated match set. If you're doing this, make sure you put the pattern inside braces so that the `[` characters won't be interpreted as command substitutions.